# Google chat auto-reply bot

Tags: google-hangouts

Is there any way to configure Google Chat so It will automatically reply when another user sends me a message? Similar to the way **vacation reply** works for GMAIL.

The trigger will be the message coming from a user. not calling any bot.

Answer (score 0):

#### Sorry, unfortunately there is no way to do that

You can set your status as "Out of Office" and that will be reflected in chat.

> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/25922?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

The API is designed for bots so there is no way via API either.

You can always make a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/), if you like.